# Signed distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

[Note, I wrote out this question, then found an answer. I thought maybe someone else would like to know it, so I'm posting the answer just in case. I'm not sure if this is the "done thing"].

Suppose I want the signed distance matrix of a vector, i.e. the distance's aren't always positive, but can be negative. You can't use

> dist()

because it returns absolute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach, which is much faster and needs less memory:

```
y <- sample (1 : 4)
distmat <- outer (y, y, `-`)
```

yields:

```
> distmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  
[1,]    0    1    3    2  
[2,]   -1    0    2    1  
[3,]   -3   -2    0   -1  
[4,]   -2   -1    1    0

## not sure why you want the upper triangular NA
distmat[upper.tri(distmat,diag=TRUE)]<-NA
```

but you possibly want:

```
> as.dist (distmat)
   1  2  3
2 -1      
3 -3 -2   
4 -2 -1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use apply:

```
y<-seq(1:10)
distmat<-as.data.frame(apply(as.matrix(y),1,function(x) y-x))
distmat[upper.tri(distmat,diag=TRUE)]<-NA
```

Comment: you can get `distmat` as `replicate(length(y), y) - t(replicate(length(y), y))` as well.

Comment: Also, the result you've produced here can be obtained by `dist(1:10, method="manhattan")`

Comment: Just hoping you are intending to use the definition of signed distance as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance , in which case it's not really clear what your interior/exterior is.  Let's be clear:  "Distance" is by strict definition nonnegative.  Are you looking for what's essentially vector locations (e.g. a point at (-3,-2) which has euclidean distance sqrt(3^2 + 2^2) from the origin) ?

Comment: @Arun, but the OP specifically asked for the possibility to get negative distances, which `method = "manhattan"` does not fulfill (the example is bad in that it doesn't show this requirement.

Comment: @cbeleites, yes, I understand, but the final result removes the negative values. That's why I mentioned, "the results you've produced **here**"... it should probably have been `distmat[lower.tri(distmat, diag=TRUE)] <- NA` instead.