# Creating a symmetric matrix populated with cross subtraction

Tags: r, perl, matrix

I have the following tab-delimited file:

```
Oslo      5
Montreal  4
Berlin    7
London    7
...
```

From that data, I am trying to construct a symmetric table populated with the subtraction among all x all, generating a table like the following:

```
          Oslo      Montreal  Berlin    London
          --------- --------- --------- ---------
Oslo              0        -1         2         2
Montreal          1         0         3         3
Berlin           -2        -3         0         0
London           -2        -3         0         0
```

The output should be a tab-delimited file.

I have been trying to do this with R and perl, which I have a basic experience, but for both I could not.
In Perl I have tryed using hash to do the subtraction, but again I have nothing.
I presume that Python should have a good solution for this, but I never tryed to write a python script, I am just starting.
I looked for it in google using several different keywords combinations and the unique similar case which I found was this, but in another language:
[Creating a symmetric matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138339/creating-a-symmetric-matrix)

Could you please help me? It will be much appreciated!

PS: Since maybe my question is too shallow, you could at least advice me what languages (R, Perl or Python), functions, packages or even some more appropriate keywords to me to keep try to solve myself.

I tryed this to get the all x all subtraction, but definitely I am lost here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

print "file:\t";
$arq1 = <STDIN>;
open (MYFILE, $arq1);
my %hash;
while (my $line=<MYFILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    (my $city,my $value) = split /\t/, $line;
    $hash{$city} = $value;
}

my %hash2;
while (my $line=<MYFILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    (my $city,my $value) = split /\t/, $line;
    $hash2{$city} = $value;
}

my @diff;
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    @diff = $hash{$key} - $hash2{$key};
}

print "difference @diff\n";
```

Comment: Hi, we request that you not use images of data or results, it makes it much more difficult for people to answer the question since they cannot copy and paste.

Comment: Hello, I tryed to copy and paste, but it got unformatted, how should I paste a table?

Comment: The easiest thing is to share some code which creates similar sample data. There are several options to solve your problem. In Python you could use the Numpy library which is commonly used for data preparation. I think the np.subtract.outer() function should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check it all!

Comment: Tip: You should ALWAYS use `use strict;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it in Perl. I hope you can learn by example. There are a few classic Perl-isms in this, which make it such a convenient language for this sort of thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Read temperature data from @ARGV files in "city<tab>temperature"
# format into a hash of city => temperature.
my %temp;
while (<>) {
    /^(.+)\t(-?\d+)\s*$/ # captures $1=city, $2=temp; enforces format
        or die "Bad data at line $.: $_";
    $temp{$1} = $2;
}

# Sort city names for rows and columns.
my @city = sort keys %temp;

# A little convenience function for printing.
sub tabulate { print join("\t", @_), "\n" }

# Print column header row.
tabulate('', @city);

# Print table body.
for my $row (@city) {
    tabulate($row, map { $temp{$_} - $temp{$row} } @city);
}

exit(0);
```

Comment: Virtually the same as the earlier answer, except it clobbers the order of the output.

Comment: @ikegami, your answer is fine too. You are correct that I have chosen not to preserve the order of the input. Your solution works better if that is what's wanted. The question did not specify the need to preserve order, and sorted output is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the file to its end, then trying to read on from there. The second loop terminates without a single pass. The solution here is to entirely eliminate the second loop because there's no point in creating two identical hashes.

The second problem is that you only output one row of data. You'll need to have nested loops (a loop for columns inside of a loop for rows).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @cities;
my %temps;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($city, $temp) = split /\t/;
   push @cities, $city;
   $temps{$city} = $temp;
}

say join "\t", "", @cities;

for my $city_y (@cities) {
   my @diffs;
   for my $city_x (@cities) {
      push @diffs, $temps{$city_x} - $temps{$city_y};
   }

   say join "\t", $city_y, @diffs;
}
```

If you're feeling a bit adventurous, a `map` would work better for the inner loop.

```
for my $city_y (@cities) {
   say join "\t", $city_y, map { $temps{$_} - $temps{$city_y} } @cities;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working, when I enter the file it seems to start to process it, but it does not finish, seems to enter in some infinite loop, something like this

Comment: This version is more conventional in that it expects the file name on the command line. (Alternatively, the data can be fed via its STDIN.)

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain to me what is happening in the for loop? The $# creates an index, right? but what means "0..$#"? Because its seems to be calling the same for $y and $x.

Comment: `$#cities` is the highest index of the array `@cities`. Actually, we don't need the indexes into the arrays (just the elements themselves), so I've simplified the answer

Comment: THank you very much, now it worked, there was a little error here: "my ($city, $temp) = split /t/;" it should be "my ($city, $temp) = split /\t/;", now it's fine \o/

Comment: Woops ! Fixed .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in R. Maybe not the cleanest but it's one :

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(city = c("Oslo","Paris","Londres","Lima","Lyon","Memphis","Ouagadougou"),
                 pop = runif(7, min = 5000, max = 10000))

result <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df)))
names(result) <- df$city
row.names(result) <- df$city

for(city in df$city) {
  tmp <- df$pop - df$pop[df$city == city]
  result[,as.character(city)] <- tmp
}
```

The next three lines allows to transform the row names as a classic column :

```
result$city <- row.names(result)
row.names(result) <- 1:nrow(result)
result2 <- result %>% dplyr::select(city, everything())
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, read in the data (shown reproducibly in the Note at the end), create a numeric country vector from that whose names are the country names and use `outer` to create the desired matrix.

```
country <- setNames(DF[[2]], DF[[1]])
-outer(country, country, "-")
```

giving:

```
         Oslo Montreal Berlin London
Oslo        0       -1      2      2
Montreal    1        0      3      3
Berlin     -2       -3      0      0
London     -2       -3      0      0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Oslo      5
Montreal  4
Berlin    7
London    7"

# DF <- read.table("myfile")
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: That's nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to give you the signs you want, but the `dist()` function in r will get you started.

```
x <- c(5,4,7,7)
names <- c("Oslo", "Montreal", "Berlin", "London")
names(x) <- names
dist(x, upper=TRUE, diag = TRUE)
```

```
         Oslo Montreal Berlin London
Oslo        0        1      2      2
Montreal    1        0      3      3
Berlin      2        3      0      0
London      2        3      0      0
```

The second answer here is also in an answer below [Signed distance matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961747/signed-distance-matrix-in-r)

Comment: I'm thinking about the sign issue and will add when I know. Or someone else with comment.